# How to drill down into this JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to drill down into this JSON response to save the location data into the location property.

```
endDate: `${ post.EventEndDate }`, // This works
location:  `${ post.Location.values.en-GB) }` // This is not working
```

JSON:

```
[
{
EventStartDate: "2019-12-03T00:00:00",
IsFeatured: false,
EventCategories: [
"Exhibition"
],
Location: "{"values":{"en-GB":"Paris, France"},"dtdGuid":"1355073c-2e61-439a-a8a7-2f3c1263d6a2"}",
SyncId: "17119-PGPI"
}
]
```

How can I access the en-GB value? Struggling with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSON.parse(data.Location).values['en-GB']
```

'data.Location' has a JSON string, Should be parsed like JSON.parse(data.Location).

'en-GB' isn't a valid identifier, Should be accessed like ['en-GB']

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the location is a different embedded JSON object stored as a string.
You will need to do something like `post.Location = JSON.parse(post.Location)` before you can access sub-element of `post.Location`.